# Нужно ли тире и запятая в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Моя подруга - шахматистка, сегодня выиграла турнир по шахматам.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Моя подруга - шахматистка, сегодня выиграла турнир по шахматам.***

Такой вариант пунктуационного оформления возможен.

Если же акцент делается не на том, что подруга — шахматистка, а на том, что подруга выиграла турнир, то возможен и такой вариант:

> ***Моя подруга, шахматистка, сегодня выиграла турнир по шахматам.***

Answer (score 0):

По правилам тире ставится между подлежащим и именной частю сказуемого, если они выражены сущ. в И.п., но не ставится в простых по составу предложениях разговорного стиля: Моя мать инженер; Мой брат школьник.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Заданное предложение разговорного стиля, но сложное по сотаву. Какое же будет решение?

Я полагаю,что все зависит от конкретной ситуации общения и в конечном счете определяется расстановкой ударений, например:

(1) *А чем занимается твоя подруга? — **Моя подруга шахматИстка,** сегодня выиграла турнир по шахматам.*

(2) *Я хочу рассказать вам о своей подруге. **Моя подрУга — шахматИстка,** сегодня выиграла турнир по шахматам.*

**Дополнение.**

Моя подруга, **шахматистка**, сегодня выиграла турнир **по шахматам,** а моя подруга, **гимнастка**, выиграла турнир **по гимнастике**. На тавтологию вроде бы похоже.